# How to add a progress bar in my python function?

Tags: python, progress-bar

Goos evening everyone.
I have a script which I run from a prompt.
It is an OCR script that takes about 20 seconds to perform an answer.

I would like to add a progress bar to show users that the treatment is in progress...

I have no idea how to do that.
All the progress bars I found so far are based on time completion, not on task/treatment completion.

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image

import pytesseract
import re
import time


def extract_quantity_and_cip13_from_image(filename):
    ocr = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
    filtre = re.compile(r'G ([0-9]+).*([0-9]{13})')
    resultat = filtre.findall(ocr)
    return resultat


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Activation du script pour OCR de facture OCP'
    print 'Entrez la localisation du fichier source'
    fichiersource = raw_input()
    print 'Lancement OCR et Filtrage pour affichage des quantités et codes CIP13'
    resultat = extract_quantity_and_cip13_from_image(fichiersource)
    print 'Voici les quantités et codes CIP13 identifiés dans le fichier source :'
    print resultat
```

Any help welcome!

Comment: how would you measure progress?

Comment: then an activity indicator will be fine, just to show users that the script is not dead...

Comment: `print 'the script is running...'`

Answer (score 0):

Try [progressbar](https://github.com/niltonvolpato/python-progressbar) which may return a different value every time its
update method is called:

Here is an example:

```
import progressbar
import time
bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=20, widgets=[progressbar.Bar('=', '[', ']'), ' ', progressbar.Percentage()])
bar.start()
for i in range(10):
    bar.update(i+1)
    time.sleep(1)
bar.finish()
```

Output:

```
(venv) ➜  python test.py
[=======================                                    ]  40%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also use Tkinter [progressbar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#ttk.Progressbar)

Comment: This feels more like a comment than a full answer. At least provide some working code and explanation on what the code is doing. Link dumping for an answer seems rather low effort and barely a full answer.